# Stop SQL query based on count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to develop a SQL Server 2016 query which can quit/stop execution after reaching a certain condition?

We developed a stored procedure which should return data only when the count of distinct records returned from a `SELECT` statement is less than 10K. So the procedure first gets the count of distinct values, and then runs the `SELECT` statement to fetch the actual data to return. If the counts return more then 10K, it will simply return the count instead of running the query again to fetch the actual data.

The table has close to 80 million records in production, for certain input parameters, it returns results in 10-15 seconds when the result has less than 10K records.

For certain input parameters, the procedure runs for close to 4-5 minutes and returns the count around 15-20 million as output.

I am looking for a way to force stop the count query as soon as it reaches the 10001th record.

Stored procedure will look something like this (in the real procedure, the select statement will have multiple conditions in the `WHERE` clause):

```
DECLARE @Count BIGINT

SELECT @Count = COUNT(DISTINCT ZIP) 
FROM dbo.Member (NOLOCK)
WHERE FirstName = @FirstName

IF @Count < 10001
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Member
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Count --When Count is greater than 10K, returns just count
END
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean like: SELECT TOP 10000 column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition; ? Or there is another problem I am not seeing?

Comment: Is `MemberNumber` really duplicated?

Comment: @Koksalb The procedure should return data only when the SELECT query returns less than 10K records. If there is more than 10K records, the procedure should not return data instead it should just return the count and not the data. So TOP keyword will not help in my case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query I gave is just for example. I edited the query to count ZIP instead of Member number. Hope it makes more sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a temporary table:

```
select top 10001 m.* 
into #member
from dbo.Member m
where . . . ;
```

Then:

```
if (@@rowcount > 10000)
begin
    select count(distinct MemberNumber)
    from . . .
end;
else
begin
    select *
    from #member;
end;
```

At the very least, this incurs the overhead of the `count(distinct)` only when necessary.

This will not speed the query in those cases -- although getting rid of the `distinct` would probably have a big effect on performance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try the temp table approach you suggested. We have duplicate records in the table, so distinct cannot be avoided in the query. Thanks again for your suggestion.